# How to resolve 'protocol must not be null' for CopySnapshotRequest across regions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am attempting to move an EC2 snapshot from one region to another.

When creating a basic Ec2 snapshot copy and copying it to a second Region I get the error protocol must not be null.  It appears that the host is also null when you get to the point in the code that will require a host.  From my understanding I do not need to provide the protocol (http/https) or the host details when copying a snapshot the is NOT encrypted.  It appears that the AWS code should do this behind the scenes.

Off the top of my head this seems like an aws issue but there is not much feedback on the AWS SDK for Java V2 yet as I have checked here as well as github.

Program exception: 
**java.lang.NullPointerException: protocol must not be null**

I have tried adding the destinationRegion to the builder but that also results in the same error.

Execution environment is Amazon Java 11.0.3
I have tried with software.amazon.awssdk versions 2.7.11 all the way through 2.7.29

Basic code snippet

```
    String amazonAccessKeyId = "amazonAccessKeyId";
    String amazonSecretKeyId = "amazonSecretKeyId";
    String baseRegionName = "baseRegionName"; // Region.AP_NORTHEAST_1.id(); or where ever your snapshot is located
    String remoteRegionName = "remoteRegionName "; // Region.AP_NORTHEAST_1.id(); or where ever your snapshot is located
    String snapshotId = "snapshotId"; // You will need a snapshot to work with this code

    // Setup AWS remote client with credentials
    AwsCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(amazonAccessKeyId, amazonSecretKeyId);

    Ec2Client amazonEc2RemoteRegionClient = Ec2Client.builder()
                    .region(Region.of(remoteRegionName))
                    .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                    .build();

    // Setup request
    CopySnapshotRequest request = CopySnapshotRequest.builder()
                    .sourceRegion(Region.of(baseRegionName).id())
                    .sourceSnapshotId(snapshotId)
                    .description("Foo Bar Testing...")
                    .build();

    // Invoke copy from remote region to pull in snapshot from source/default region
    // This is the line in question
    CopySnapshotResponse result = amazonEc2RemoteRegionClient.copySnapshot(request);
```

Stack trace follows

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: protocol must not be null.
        at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.Validate.paramNotNull(Validate.java:117)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest.standardizeProtocol(DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest.java:63)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest.<init>(DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest.java:52)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest.<init>(DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest.java:41)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest$Builder.build(DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest.java:331)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest$Builder.build(DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest.java:170)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.transform.internal.GeneratePreSignUrlInterceptor.modifyHttpRequest(GeneratePreSignUrlInterceptor.java:102)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionInterceptorChain.modifyHttpRequestAndHttpContent(ExecutionInterceptorChain.java:99)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseClientHandler.runModifyHttpRequestAndHttpContentInterceptors(BaseClientHandler.java:123)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseClientHandler.finalizeSdkHttpFullRequest(BaseClientHandler.java:68)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:106)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:73)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.DefaultEc2Client.copySnapshot(DefaultEc2Client.java:2808)
```

I expect the snapshot to be copied to the new region specified, without error, and not encrypted.

As a side note I have submitted this to Amazon through my support system and I am awaiting a response from them.  I will update this post once they respond to my request.

Comment: I believe you need to add a destination region too in your builder

Comment: According to the documentation, a destination Region and presigned Url are only required when the snapshot is encrypted, which mine are not.  I ran the test application again with the destination region and it still fails as the same error.

Answer (score 0):

copySnapshot
sdk error,builder with presignedUrl can skip it